# Getting Full HTML in Java

Tags: java, html

I am working on a project that will parse through a database's(specificall New York Times online database http://query.nytimes.com/search/sitesearch/#/McCain/from20061201to20080603/allresults/1/allauthors/oldest/) html code to find certain keywords, but it the code I got from oracle is not working to get the full html. I have been able to use this code before for other projects, so I am not sure why it is not reading off all of the html.

Thanks :)

```
   URL oracle = new URL("http://query.nytimes.com/search/sitesearch/#/McCain/from20061201to20080603/allresults/1/allauthors/oldest/");
    URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
    yc.connect();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
    System.out.println(yc.getContentType());
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working' and 'full HTML'?

Comment: I mean that my project only prints off part of the HTML and is missing the part of the HTML that I want, which I suspect is because the webpage is loading

Comment: Sorry for being so vague

Comment: It's because that query can't work without the JS on the page being evaluated. Notice you have a fragment (#...) on the page, that isn't even sent to the server. You won't be able to scrape this way.

Comment: How do you think that I should fix it then?

Comment: Added sanest thing as an answer. You'll need to do some work to figure out how the API works but it will be a lot easier than scraping HTML in the end

Answer (score 3):

The NYT search pages use on-page javascript to make calls to an API which returns the search results as JSON and then are formatted as HTML. Since you are looking to collect data, using this API is likely what you want and has the advantage of requiring no scraping and returning the data in a structured, easy-to-process format. You will have to figure out how the API works by using the dev tools of a browser or look whether others have documented it. Here is how a simple query for 'foo' looks -

http://query.nytimes.com/svc/add/v1/sitesearch.json?q=foo&spotlight=true&facet=true

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how would I set it to look between two different dates? I am looking for it right now

Comment: @KevinBender That's a different question entirely, I think I've answered your initial one.